# Copy today's data from File A to File B in google sheets using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to copy all today's data from `File A` google sheet (looping all sheets) to File B google sheet.

see below code that doesn't work for all sheets from `File A`. It is coping from 1st sheet only.
and another question, is it possible to query today's date but not looping the column?

```
function copyrange() {

  var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var destFileSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CHhQALWDLIWiBxGwSxZx0BjWTYSpHvxxlITE")
  var ds = destFileSS.getSheetByName('Submissions');
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-0', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
//looping each sheet and checking column A has today's date
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceSheets.length ; i++ ) {
        var sheet = sourceSheets[i];
        var sourceDateRange = sheet.getRange('A:A');
        var DateRangevalues = (sourceDateRange.setNumberFormat("@").getValues());
        for (sDate=0;sDate<DateRangevalues.length;sDate++) {
            if (DateRangevalues[i] == today) {
                data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(sDate+1,1,1,20).getValues());
                //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
                j.push(sDate);
            }
        }
         //Copy data array to destination sheet
        ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); 
        data =[];
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working correctly because you are using the wrong index variable. Replace `DateRangevalues[i]` with `DateRangevalues[sDate]` to make it better.

Alternatively, use JavaScript `Array` methods, like this:

```js
function copyAllDataToAnotherSpreadsheet() {
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('1CHhQALWDLIWiBxGwSxZx0BjWTYSpHvxxlITE')
    .getSheetByName('Submissions');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const todayString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  const sourceSheets = ss.getSheets();
  let result = [];
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const data = sheet.getRange('A1:J')
      .getDisplayValues()
      .filter(row => row[0] === todayString);
    result = result.concat(data);
  });
  targetSheet.getRange(getLastRow() + 1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```